# Necessary Condition for convergence of a series (Theorem 3.23 Baby Rudin)?Why it's not sufficient?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I can't seem to grasp this theorem as put forward by Rudin.

if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=0$

This follows immediately from the cauchy criterion for series.
We just pick $n=m$.
Shouldn't then be also a sufficient condition?

Comment: Consider the harmonic series (i.e., $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$).

Comment: @Chris: not from zero!

Comment: It is not sufficient because we have a counter-example,  as shown by Chris. It's a classic counter-example, though

Comment: Yes i do know that there are series which do not converge despite the fact that its terms becomes infinitesimal. My main concern was with the proof: why  the cauchy criterion can't be used to show that the condition is also sufficient?

Comment: Because when $\lim a_n=0$, the sequence of the partial sums $\{\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\}_N$ is not necessarily a Cauchy sequence at all. How would you then use the "Cauchy criterion" for the series?

Comment: Thanks Jack it's clear now, you're right. Sorry for the dumb question, i didn't put much effort in thinking about it i guess.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Lol, yes, my mistake!

Comment: Consider that $0<\sqrt {n+1}';-\sqrt n\;=$ $(\sqrt {n+1}\;+\sqrt n)^{-1}$ $<1/2\sqrt n\; \to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$  But $\sum_{j=1}^n(\sqrt {n+1}\;-\sqrt n\;)=-1+\sqrt {n+1}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read thoroughly.

Rudin has written explicitly in his book:

> [image]